# Fn+F4 to suspend on a Thinkpad Carbon X1

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, power-management, mate-desktop, thinkpad

On my old Thinkpad, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is a dedicated supsend key that Just Works in MATE (it locks the screen and then goes to suspended-to-RAM state).

On the 4th gen Thinkpad X1 Carbon, there is no suspend key on the keyboard: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is for muting the microphone. Given that I don't need a dedicated media key to mute the mike, how do I remap <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to suspend-to-RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a way to remap <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, I've discovered that <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (as in, the normal numeral key) works by default to trigger suspend-to-RAM.